# Disabling Auto MDI/MDI-x in switches

Tags: switch

Can we disable Auto MDI/MDI-x? If so, how to do it in a DLink DES-1024D unmanaged switch? Are there any advantages in disabling Auto MDI/MDI-x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WHY?!  Auto MDI/MDI-x is one of the best features of switches IMO.

Also, if your switch is unmanaged (ie, no web, telnet, SNMP interfaces) then no, you can't change the firmware of the switch [which is effectively what you'd need to do]

Comment: I was trying to implement a routing protocol. In its manual it was suggested to disable Auto MDI/MDI-x if possible to avoid network loop!!

Comment: Which routing protocol?